# Is creating HttpClient expensive?

Tags: android, httpclient

I had seen a few examples in Android implement maybeCreateHttpClient(), especially in Google sample, which it does is to check if HttpClient object is instantiated, if not, instantiate it, and reuse it.

Why this approach? Is creating new HttpClient expensive?

Comment: I don't know about expensive, but it can be stateful. Cookie jars and stuff like that.

Comment: Good point @Thilo. If you perform some kind of authentication you will need to keep the same httpclient otherwise your credentials will not be passed on for each subsequent call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a connection pool (eg. ThreadSafeClientConnManager) to manage your clients.

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
registry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

ClientConnectionManager connman = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
client = new DefaultHttpClient(connman, params);
```

client is a singleton object which can be reused, to fire a request:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
```

Comment: So is that mean, subsequent httpclient call will be put into queue, until the previous done?

Comment: You can set how many concurrency request can be fired at a time, check the javadoc of ThreadSafeClientConnManager. If there are no more slot in the pool, further request will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

A HttpClient is fairly large and complex object. You might make tens (or probably more) http calls in your app. If you created a new one for each http request you would quickly run into memory problems and would certainly notice garbage collection slow downs.

The http client is a generic component to help you make http calls, just reuse it. There is no reason not too.

Comment: But reusing it can sometimes cause "Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated." Any good design pattern?